# Chrome open in new window if change location.href shows address bar

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have this web app and I have saved it to the desktop and open as new window, now it opened as an app, but when I change the location using javascript location.href, the address bar showed up, how do I hide the address bar ? Thanks.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot above, if I change the location of the page, the address bar at the top shows the url (192.168.100.7/charas), how do I hide this bar ?

Comment: Why do you need to change location.href via JavaScript?

Comment: because I need to

Comment: Why? You already have a shortcut.

Comment: what shotcut ? you mean the buttons ? yes by clicking the buttons, it will trigger location.href, thus changing the url, and thus the address bar shows.

Comment: I've tried my best to clarify the situation but didn't succeed. Maybe someone else will have better luck.